# Calculus: Sketching a graph that satisfies the following conditions

Tags: calculus, limits, graphing-functions

The following question is from our reviewer for our upcoming exams:

> $\ast$ 3. Sketch the graph of a function $f$ satisfying the following conditions:
>   (i). $-5,-3,-2,-1,0$ and $2$ are the only zeros of $f$,
>   (ii). $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to - 3} f(x) = 4; \displaystyle \lim_{x\to-1^{-}}f(x) = -\infty, \displaystyle\lim_{x\to-1^+}f(x) = 0,\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0}f(x) = +\infty,$ and
>   (iii). $f$ is continuous at all numbers in the open intervals $(-\infty, -3),(-3,-1),(-1,0),(0,+\infty)$.

[Source.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBb8o.jpg)

---

Here's what I came up with for the past hour:
[image: My solution]

Am I going the right way? I don't have any clue to what does it mean by "zeroes of f" but what I feel is that it relates to points that are in the $x$-axis that when substituted to the function, it results to zero.

Also, are there some tips/ review links on how can I visualize better on sketching a graph with conditions that satisfies it? I find it really hard to visualize the graph =(

Thank you =)

Comment: Isn´t 1) about the graph being at $f(x)=0$ when $x={-5,-3,-2,-1,0,2}$

Comment: that's what I think it is but I'm not so sure though

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

1. zeros of $f$ are values $c$ such that $f(c) = 0$.
2. I believe there is  a problem with your graph at $x = -3$.
3. Your graph is not defined on $(2,\infty)$, so I don't believe it is continuous on $(0,\infty)$

This is what I am getting:
[image]

Those should be negative numbers on the left. Hehe.